# $ X \sim B(200,1/9) $ Calculate $ E[2^{x+3}] $

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$
X \sim B(200,1/9)
$$

Calculate

$$
E[2^{x+3}]
$$

What i did:

$$
E[2^{x+3}] = E[2^x2^3] = 2^3E[2^x] = 8E[2^x] = 8(\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}2^xPr(X=x)) = 8(\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}2^x\binom{200}{x}(1/9)^x(8/9)^{200-x}) = 
$$
$$
= 8(\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\binom{200}{x}(2/9)^x(8/9)^{200-x})
$$

Here I'm stuck. How can i calculate this serie?

I solved it using MGF, but i am not allowed to use it.

$$
8E[(e^{\ln 2})^X] = 8M_X(t=\ln 2) = 8(8/9+(1/9)e^{ln2})^{200} = 8(10/9)^{200}
$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ take value only up to $200$.

$$
= 8(\sum_{x=0}^{200}\binom{200}{x}(2/9)^x(8/9)^{200-x}) = 8(\frac  29 +\frac 8 9)^{200}
$$ by Bimomial Theorem.

Comment: Oh, right, thank you, i forgot the the expansion of $(x+y)^n$